# Fill spaces with characters of the previous line using awk

Tags: awk, whitespace

I would like to solve the following problem. Given an input file like this one:

```
1 1 1
1 0 1
1   1
0
1
```

I would like to replace each space with the character of the same column but of the previous row. The process must go on until all the columns will have the same number of not empty elements as the column with the maximum length. The first row does not contain blank characters and the elements can be 0, 1 or -1.
In that example, I would like to have this output file:

```
1 1 1
1 0 1
1 0 1
0 0 1
1 0 1
```

I have tried to write this script:

```
#! /bin/bash

cat input.dat | awk '{if(FNR == 1) {
            for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
                first[i] = $i;
            max = NF;
            print $0
            }  else {
            for(i=1; i<=max; i++) {
                if($i != "")
                    second[i] = $i;
            }
            for(i=1; i<=max; i++) {
                if($i == "")
                    printf("%d\t", first[i])
                else {
                    printf("%d\t", second[i])   
                    first[i] = second[i];
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
            }
        }' > output.dat
```

but it does not work at all. Can you help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: On your 3rd line of input, $3 will be null, not $2...

Comment: Do you mean that the control: if($i != "") doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `gnu awk`

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="1 1 1 1 1" '$3!~/0|1/ {$3=p3} $5!~/0|1/ {$5=p5} {p3=$3;p5=$5;print $1,$3,$5}'
1 1 1
1 0 1
1 0 1
0 0 1
1 0 1
```

---

A more portable version using `awk`

```
awk '{f1=substr($0,1,1);f2=substr($0,3,1);f3=substr($0,5,1)} f2!~/0|1/ {f2=p2} $3!~/0|1/ {f3=p3} {p2=f2;p3=f3;print f1,f2,f3}' file
1 1 1
1 0 1
1 0 1
0 0 1
1 0 1
```

Comment: I just copied yours idea, cred to you :)

Comment: @Anna You are welcome.  Updated my post with a portable version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use GNU awk and fixed width input parsing, by setting `FIELDWIDTHS="2 2 2"` in a `BEGIN{}` block. Then you will know which field is missing.

However, your `-1` input value may mess that up, depending on how it is spaced, so you may need run your data through `sed` first to replace `-1` with, say `2` and then reverse that out with another `sed` after the `awk` is finished.

```
sed 's/-1/2/g' file | awk ... | sed 's/2/-1/g'
```